# How to set min_size upload File in Code Igniter?

Tags: codeigniter, upload

I want stablish a minimum size when the user upload a photo, the minimun Size is 3MB, how I can define this?

In the controller where I call Upload I have this

```
$config['min_size'] = '3000';
```

In the Upload.php, What I need to do?

Comment: there is only max size in CI

Answer (score 0):

There's no option to do this, nor should there be one - it just doesn't make sense.

I suppose you're trying to put a minimum "quality" limit on photos, but there are two problems with that:

- While filesize would (logically) increase with quality, they are not the same thing.
- Determining image quality would be a job for an images-related library, not one for uploads.